# Windows recognizes jpackage .exe installer as an virus

Tags: windows, javafx, installation, jpackage

So I created a jpackage installer, but there are two problems:

-The browser detects it as a virus, when a user downloads it, (picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8o8k.png) )

-Operating system detects it as a virus either, and shows me a smartscreen protection screen.

How can I get rid of this two things?

Is there an offical guide to do it?

I read about signing the installer, but I got confused with that. And is that what is causing the problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: It sounds like the Windows alert that lets you know you are about to install something Windows has not verified.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/124017/trying-to-install-my-application-but-getting-a-sec.html

Comment: My app is a simple auto clicker

Comment: Which version of jpackage are you using? (Java version)

Comment: Java version 17

Comment: That message doesn’t say that the app is a virus, just that it hasn’t been verified.  If you want Microsoft to be able to verify your application, check with Microsoft Development support on what you need to do to allow them to do that.